# Integrating Chartboost on Android 2.1+

Tags: android, reflection, chartboost

I integrated Chartboost into my Android app. The app is for Android 2.1+. Chartboost SDK is for Android 2.2+.

I do Android SDK version check (make sure it is 2.2+) before I request a Chartboost ad, but some users are still complaining of crashing. I believe these are 2.1 users, although it could be something else. I am unable to replicate crashing on my 2.1 devices.

How can I make sure that Chartboost calls do not crash? I already have all Chartboost calls wrapped in try/catch blocks.

NOTE: this can be considered a general question on how to support different Android platform versions.

Thanks.

Comment: How and why does iylt crash? Show us the stack traces...

Comment: I am unable to replicate crashing on my 2.1 devices, so I don't have logs